# Can I do an impdp with a file on my local computer

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I was given a dump file which is currently on my local computer.  I want to import this to our Oracle 11G DB which is hosted on a server.  Do I need to move this file to the server to do the impdp or is there a way that I can do the impdp while referencing that the file is on my local PC?

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible, provided the user that the DB service is running as can access the file share.

If the above is true, then you would have to create the directory object:

```
create directory MYIMPORTDIR as '\\mycomp\mydir';
```

then run your impdp like:

```
impdp [username]/[pass] directory=MYIMPORTDIR dumpfile=expdat_1234.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the dump-file to an area where the database has access to it referenced inside the database as a directory object. You can run impdp from your local computer.